# Retrieving Data from GEAR S3 Heart Rate Monitor (HRM) to Mobile or Server

Tags: android, tizen, samsung-gear

I have used the Tizen sample Heart Rate Monitor code for Samsung Gear S3 from https://developer.tizen.org/ko/community/tip-tech/accessing-heart-rate-monitor-hrm-sensor-data-native-applications?langredirect=1

I want to develop Android or Tizen for Retrieving Data from the Heart Rate Monitor which is in S3 Gear. I found the sample code from https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/web-application/sensors/human-activity-monitor?langredirect=1#retrieve

How can I integrate this. Pls share your ideas. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use SAP (Samsung Accessory Protocol) to communicate between Android and Gear S3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [Samsung Accessory SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/accessory), you can develop an app in Android which can communicate with Tizen app(Gear). 
Here is a working example

[How to integrate Samsung Gear Steps in android Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233692/how-to-integrate-samsung-gear-steps-in-android-application/40529913#40529913)

**Edit:**

Here i am giving the code to measure Heart Rate and return back to Android phone when a request is sent from Android . I have just modified code from [previously mentioned post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233692/how-to-integrate-samsung-gear-steps-in-android-application/40529913#40529913) and sharing here.

Here i am giving  only contents from `dataOnReceive` function

```
            if (!SAAgent.channelIds[0]) {
                createHTML("Something goes wrong...NO CHANNEL ID!");
                return;
            }

            function sendHrData(heartRate){
                 // return Data to Android
                 SASocket.sendData(SAAgent.channelIds[0], 'HR: '+heartRate);
                 createHTML("Send massage:<br />" +
                             newData);

             tizen.humanactivitymonitor.stop('HRM');

            }

            var heartRateData=0;

            function onsuccessCB(hrmInfo) {

                console.log('Heart rate: ' + hrmInfo.heartRate);
                heartRateData = hrmInfo.heartRate;
                // holding 15 seconds as HRM sensor needs some time 
                setTimeout(function(){
                    sendHrData(heartRateData);
                    }, 15000);

            }

            function onerrorCB(error) {
                tizen.humanactivitymonitor.stop('HRM');
                console.log('Error occurred: ' + error.message);
            }



            function onchangedCB(hrmInfo) {
                //alert("onChanged...");
                tizen.humanactivitymonitor.getHumanActivityData('HRM', onsuccessCB, onerrorCB);

            }

            tizen.humanactivitymonitor.start('HRM', onchangedCB);
```

And this code continuously returning Heart Rate. Please modified according to your requirements, i am just sharing the idea to communicate between Android phone and Samsung Gear.

[image]

**Send Data to Server:**

You can use **Ajax** or **XmlHttpRequest** to send data to server

**Ajax:**

```
    function sendDataToServer() {
            'use strict';

            console.log( "ready!" );
              $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: "http://YOUR_URL",
                success: function (data) {
                      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                 }
           });
        }
```

**XmlHttpRequest:**

```
function postDataToServer() {
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            alert("data posted successfully..");
        } else {
            alert("failed to send data..");
        }
    }
}

xmlHttp.open("POST", "YOUR_URL");

xmlHttp.send("_TEST_STRING_DATA");
```

[Auto generated code from REST viewer not working in Tizen IDE(Wearable) web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40590871/auto-generated-code-from-rest-viewer-not-working-in-tizen-idewearable-web-app/40602735#40602735)

[XmlHttpRequest on Tizen TV exits application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40737184/xmlhttprequest-on-tizen-tv-exits-application/40755413#40755413)

[RESTful service on emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054522/restful-service-on-emulator/44065848#44065848)

> Note: You need to install [Samsung Gear](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.app.watchmanager&hl=en) application in your Android phone.

Comment: I have test this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233692/how-to-integrate-samsung-gear-steps-in-android-application/40529913#40529913 and its working fine in Wear and Mobile. But I want to know how I can integrate this Code with the Heart Rate Monitor. So that I can get Heart Rate Data in my Android mobile. Pls share if you have any sample code. Thanks a lot

Comment: I check the above code but its giving error. Can you share your sample code in full which you developed for android mobile and Samsung Gear Watch. Thanks in advance

Comment: Full code https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6KEP_6UcxrATllCWTlmeUh1M28/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have just modified dataOnReceive of Tizen part

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. How can I pass the data to a server directly from the watch.

Comment: If it works, then select it as accepted :-) You can send data to server using Http request simply

Comment: I found one http Request code. Can I use the below code var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "get_data.php";
var params = "lorem=ipsum&name=binny";
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);

Comment: Yes! you can .. i have updated the answer with Ajax ..please check ...also gave XmlHtpRequest help link

Comment: I used the above code in last (after the function(tau ) of the app.js file to send data to server and using server as localhost.But cannot send the data.

Comment: There is no errors but the data is not sending to the server

Comment: XmlHttpRequest added ...please check

Comment: I cannot connect the App from Mobile to Wear after inserting the XmlHttpRequest: code.

Comment: please add internet privilege and allow domain policy according to links given above