# Tizen Wearable 4.0 - S Health pedometer

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk

Is there a way to get daily step count in Tizen Wearable 4.0 - web (html + css + js)?

I'm making a Tizen Watch Face and I want to show it

Comment: I think you have to preserve step count values within 24 hours.

Comment: @Yasinshihab yes, I can do it with just pure step counter, but Can I somehow get the data from S Health? I know it is possible, because some watch faces have it. And I can add it in the Samsung Watch Designer, so I'm just asking how to do it in JS.

Comment: you need to use S Health SDK for Android .....also need Companion app SDK to transfer data to Gear

Comment: Yeah, I know it is possible with tizen native. But with JS? Do you have any documentation?

Comment: Yeah ....it is also available for JS ...check here https://developer.samsung.com/health/android 

Communication between gear and android https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49877474/retrieving-data-from-gear-s3-heart-rate-monitor-hrm-to-mobile-or-server/49892664#49892664

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option for your need is to use [setAccumulativePedometerListener](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/5.0.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/wearable/tizen/humanactivitymonitor.html#HumanActivityMonitorManager::setAccumulativePedometerListener). It get data from SHealth and will be invoked when new accumulative pedometer data will be available. This listener collect's data when display is turned off.